# NSURLConnection Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection

What is "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1020 UserInfo=0x1694a0 "Operation could not be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1020.)"" due to ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error codes you get from NSURLConnection are in `NSURLError.h` and `CFNetworkErrors.h`, as well as [this Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/). It looks like -1020 is `kCFURLErrorDataNotAllowed`, which says:

> "The connection failed because data use is currently not allowed on the device."

Answer (score 1):

To see CFNetworkErrors, go to CFNetwork.CFNetworkErrors

CFNetworkErrors.cfurlErrorDataNotAllowed.rawValue (Int32 value = -1020)

```
case cfurlErrorBadURL = -1000
case cfurlErrorTimedOut = -1001
case cfurlErrorUnsupportedURL = -1002
case cfurlErrorCannotFindHost = -1003
case cfurlErrorCannotConnectToHost = -1004
case cfurlErrorNetworkConnectionLost = -1005
case cfurlErrorDNSLookupFailed = -1006
case cfurlErrorHTTPTooManyRedirects = -1007
case cfurlErrorResourceUnavailable = -1008
case cfurlErrorNotConnectedToInternet = -1009
case cfurlErrorRedirectToNonExistentLocation = -1010
case cfurlErrorBadServerResponse = -1011
case cfurlErrorUserCancelledAuthentication = -1012
case cfurlErrorUserAuthenticationRequired = -1013
case cfurlErrorZeroByteResource = -1014
case cfurlErrorCannotDecodeRawData = -1015
case cfurlErrorCannotDecodeContentData = -1016
case cfurlErrorCannotParseResponse = -1017
case cfurlErrorInternationalRoamingOff = -1018
case cfurlErrorCallIsActive = -1019
case cfurlErrorDataNotAllowed = -1020
case cfurlErrorRequestBodyStreamExhausted = -1021
case cfurlErrorAppTransportSecurityRequiresSecureConnection = -1022
case cfurlErrorFileDoesNotExist = -1100
case cfurlErrorFileIsDirectory = -1101
case cfurlErrorNoPermissionsToReadFile = -1102
case cfurlErrorDataLengthExceedsMaximum = -1103
case cfurlErrorFileOutsideSafeArea = -1104
```

Answer (score 0):

It can not decode the data......

Comment: That's right the error of means the data can not be interpreted.

Answer (score -2):

Surprisingly, I can not see the error code -1020 there.:(.

```
typedef enum
{

   NSURLErrorBadServerResponse = -1011,

   NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication = -1012,

   NSURLErrorUserAuthenticationRequired = -1013,

   NSURLErrorZeroByteResource = -1014,

   NSURLErrorCannotDecodeRawData = -1015,

   NSURLErrorCannotDecodeContentData = -1016,

   NSURLErrorCannotParseResponse = -1017,
}
```

I believe that this one is a right table right?